# Can i get source code of msi file in linux and add some conditions?

Tags: linux, unix, windows-installer, license-key

i have a **.msi** file . i want to add functionality in the installer. 
i want to add

> License Key Condition ,when someone try to install the application.
>   i don't want others to use this application. Only for those who have key for this software.Please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: Every tool that I know of has a way to add a dialog for a license key, so how are you building the MSI file?

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I am really wondering why you have added "linux" to your tags list? How does Linux enter the picture?

Answer (score 0):

This question needs some improvement and clarification I think, but I will attempt an answer.

The application itself should be designed to allow license keys to only be accessible for certain users. Generally this involves storing the license in HKCU rather than HKLM. You cannot really change this in the setup, it is the application that will expect to read the license key from a predetermined source. Some applications are able to store license keys both per-user or per-machine - it all depends on its design. What application is this?

One way to "emulate" this for applications that only register the license key per-machine (for all users), is to remove the shortcuts to launch the application for users who do not have rights to use the application. This can involve installing the MSI "per-user", but it doesn't always work as intended.

It also depends on how you will distribute this software. Does it get installed remotely from a deployment system such as SCCM, or will you install interactively on every computer? If the latter is the case, you can install as the user who will use the application, and check if there is an option called "Install for current user" (or equivalent). If you deploy remotely you should create a transform to set the same option (install for current user) and invoke the install via SCCM whilst that user is logged in.

Where does Linux fit into this equation? Are you running Wine or some emulation software?